# Selenium WebDriver - Getting NoSuchElementException error even element is present

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click on drop down box in my application and Xpath is  : `//*[@id='sel2O5_chzn']/a`
But when I try to click on it, am getting *NoSuchElementException*
Even element is present in application. Tried in IE,Chrome and Firefox still facing same issue

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sel2T1_chzn']/a")).click();
```

Tried below approch as well but no luck. Getting same *NoSuchElementException*

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sel2T1_chzn']")));
sel.selectByIndex(1);
```

Please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Can you please share the relevant HTML code for the dropdown ?

Comment: There could be 2 possibilities. 1 - element is taking time to be displayed. 2 - element is in an iframe or frame. Can u please explore these 2 possibilities. And it will help us to help u if u can provide the HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explicit` wait with that it enables you to wait for the element to be located by `WebDriver` and [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) is a list of `ExpectedConditions` you can use

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='sel2T1_chzn']")));
myDynamicElement.click();
```